# How to prevent crashing when tapping off a node

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

The code that I am writing has a problem where whenever I tap somewhere other than a node (ex. background) the app ends up crashing.

I've tried making an if let statement but it says I can't downcast a `SKnode` to a more optional type `SKSpriteNode`.
 I've also tried `if node.contains(position of touch)`.

```swift
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if let touchLocation = touch?.location(in: self) {
    let selectedNode = nodes(at: touchLocation)[0] as! SKSpriteNode

        activeObject = selectedNode
        storedData = Array(activeObject.name!)
        let platformStoredInt = storedData[2]
        storedPlatform = Int(platformStoredInt.unicodeScalars.first!.value - Unicode.Scalar("0")!.value)

        }
    }
```

Tapping on anything other than the SKSpriteNodes that are considered objects results in a SIGABRT.

Answer (score 0):

The app crashes because you are force unwrapping a value in this line:

`let selectedNode = nodes(at: touchLocation)[0] as! SKSpriteNode`

So instead, use:

```
if let selectedNode = nodes(at: touchLocation)[0] as? SKSpriteNode {

  activeObject = selectedNode
  storedData = Array(activeObject.name!)
  let platformStoredInt = storedData[2]
   storedPlatform = Int(platformStoredInt.unicodeScalars.first!.value - Unicode.Scalar("0")!.value)

}
```

**Always try to avoid the force unwrapping (as!)**. Use [Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) instead.

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties, methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil.

Comment: That helped with tapping on other nodes but tapping on the background still crashes it.

Comment: I got a SIGABRT.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException